# Using spatial index to boost distance query from point to polygon

Tags: distance, geopandas, r-tree

[Here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/spatial_index.html?highlight=sindex) introduces how to boost spatial intersection queries using R-Tree. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe) [@JHuw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/130582/jhuw) provides ways using R-Tree to calculate the nearest distance from point to point and line, respectively. Nevertheless, I have not found a solution to boost distance query from point to polygon using R-Tree. I followed those examples mentioned above and still have not figured out how to implement R-Tree in nearest distance query from point to polygon. Could anybody help me figure this out? Much appreciated. I use South America and a subset of cities from GeoPandas as an example in the following:

```
# Import libraries
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data from GeoPandas
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

south_america = world[world.continent == 'South America']
city_sub = cities[cities.index < 20]

# Plot
ax= south_america.boundary.plot()
city_sub.plot(ax=ax)

# Nearest distance from point (city_sub) to polygon (south_america) using R-Tree
# "To be finished..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more detailed walk-through of snapping points to a line using the spatial index (RTree) in geopandas that may help in this case: https://medium.com/@brendan_ward/how-to-leverage-geopandas-for-faster-snapping-of-points-to-lines-6113c94e59aa

It uses a tolerance based approach, so it only selects those that features are nearest within that tolerance.  You can use a larger tolerance in this approach, but it can increase processing time dramatically. It uses a bounding box based on that tolerance to query the features in RTree; the bigger the bounding box, the less effective it is for querying the tree.

With polygons, you have more cases to consider: a point that is within a polygon has a distance of 0.

You can handle this in 2 passes: first use a spatial join in geopandas to find all cases where the points are within polygons.  Then take all those that are not within polygons, and try to find the nearest polygon for each point.  Using a tolerance based bounding box to query RTree gives you a list of candidate polygons, then calculate the distance between the point and its candidate polygons, and take the one with the smallest distance.

You also need to decide what to do when a given point falls within multiple polygons: which one is "nearest" in that case?  One approach is to select the overlapping polygon whose centroid is closest to your point, but it really depends on your goals.

Comment: Thanks. The RTree case you mentioned is useful. Like your saying, the spatial query from point to polygon is a little bit complicated than to point or line. Geopandas is working on adding some features on nearest spatial query, I will be waiting for that functionality from Geopandas.